# Angular countdown service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval, web-worker, angular-services

I am trying to create an Angular service which uses a web worker to change countdown variable using set interval.

What I want to do is to show the count down in the view.

I can easily do this by putting all the code in controller, which works but I got struck in creating the service

I am struck. I dont know how to proceed.

I have tried this [plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/L1x7tX?p=preview)

***script.js***

```
angular.module('app', []).
controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);


function mainCtrl($scope,timer) {

$scope.time = 100;

console.log(timer.timeValue.time);

}


mainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','timer'];
```

***timer.js***

```
angular.module('app')
   .service('timer', timer);

function timer() {
  var time;
  this.timeValue = function(value) {

      var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
      worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        //console.log('From Main:'+ e.data.time);
        time = e.data.time;

    };

    worker.postMessage(time);

    return time;
};
}
```

***worker.js***

```
angular.module('app')
.service('timer', timer);

function timer() {
  var time;
this.timeValue = function(value) {

    var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        //console.log('From Main:'+ e.data.time);
        time = e.data.time;

    };

    worker.postMessage(time);

    return time;
};
}
```

What I want to do is like this. This is my earlier plunk.This do the same thing using controller.

[plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/C9Ev2K?p=preview)

Comment: Why do you have to use a web worker for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it's not working with your code. Just for the record, a countdown is not something you want to do with a Webworker, but anyway!

First of all in timer.js:

```
angular.module('app')
    .service('timer', timer);

timer.$inject=['$rootScope']

function timer($rootScope) {

    this.timeValue = function(value) {
        var time = value;
        var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
        worker.onmessage = function(e) {
            time = e.data.time;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('timerUpdate', time)
        };
        worker.postMessage(time);
    };
}
```

You have to start the var time with a value.

I injected `$rootScope` to the service, so i can `$broadcast` a message back to the main scope.

In the main script I did this:

```
function mainCtrl($scope,timer) {
    function init() {
        timer.timeValue(100);
    }
    $scope.time = 100;

    $scope.$on('timerUpdate', function(event, time) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.time = time;
        })
    })

    init();
}


mainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','timer'];
```

So, i made a Init function that gets triggered once in the beginning. That triggers your service into making a webworker.

Once the webworker gives back the message(time). The timerService sends out a `$rootScope.$broadcast` picked up by `$scope.$on()`.

The `$scope.$apply` is not really the best thing to have in a simple script like this, but it's the only thing that will force digest(Angular page update) the page and give the `$scope.time` a new value.

and last the webworker:

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
    var time = e.data;

    var timer = setInterval(toDo, 1000);

    function toDo() {
        time--;
        postMessage({
            time: time
        });
    }
}
```

(Only thing i did was change `time = time - 1` to `time--;` (shorthand version, looks beter !)

Hope this helps !

(also, just for the record, try no to use the `$rootScope` or the `$scope.$apply` function! It's not the best way to do stuff I hear, but I'm also new to Angular and haven't found anything beter for these things..)

And the plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/7IoGxFaaqQRH4AErGenl?p=preview

Comment: `$scope.$apply` is used when you need to update angular-ui from a non-angular event.

Comment: A new digest cycle is the same as updating the angular-ui, or is a digest cylce something else ?